# How to disable transitions on Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap but want to disable the blue glow around an input box when it gets focus.

I've tried
    transition: border-color 0s, box-shadow 0s;

It works fine on Firefox, IE, but Chrome just ignores this and keeps the animation.

Could anyone let me know how to disable that transition on Chrome, please?

TVMIA,

## Adam.

Comment: *:focus{
    outline:0px !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
} That will catch it for all elements, if its just input you need replace * with input

Comment: The visual display of focus is an important feature for accessibility. Try tabbing through your form, as someone using keyboard navigation would. Without focus, it's very difficult to determine your place in the page structure. (Remember, impeding accessibility can create liability for your site owner.

Comment: I have to agree with dogwood here, I'm also an accessibility engineer at my company.. I can't imagine why you would try to hide focus indication, unless you're creating a custom one to replace it.

Comment: Hi, chaps - "a custom one to replace it" - that's exactly what we're doing. I probably ought to have made that clear but was trying not to add unneeded fluff to the question. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered before, try:

```
input:focus {outline:0;}
```

Comment: I did try looking - honest! Thanks for the response. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that in a bad way, I guess I meant.. this is how I know.. ha ha.